# This problem appears when I start the application, what do I do?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-manifest

C:\Users\lenovo\StudioProjects\TESTAH\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:6:9-42 Error:
Attribute application@name at AndroidManifest.xml:6:9-42 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for  is provided.
C:\Users\lenovo\StudioProjects\TESTAH\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Validation failed, exiting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Contains the problem that appears when launching an application
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G4Z5.jpg)

This image contains the file AndroidManifest.xml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJJrM.png)

This image contains the file AndroidMainfest.xml
at android/app/src/debug
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd503.png)

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml have some error please share you `AndroidMainfest.xml` file for more clearity.

Comment: You have sent another reply containing AndroidMainfest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this line

```
   android:name=".MainActivity"
```

with

```
 android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity"
```

Comment: I replaced the same problem has not changed

Comment: share android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml file .

Comment: I have added another picture to the post that contains a request

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.big_ui_material">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>